# I need to write a fraction that has the 'min operator in the denominator

Tags: math-operators, fractions

Here is what I have typed:

```
\begin{equation*}
s_j=\frac{e_j}{\min_{1 \leq k \leq m-1} \big\{t_{jk} + t_{j(k+1)} \big\}
\end{equation*}
```

however, it is displaying as a subscript rather than UNDER the min operator.

Is this because the operator is in the denominator?

How do I fix this?

thanks
:)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Try adding `\limits_` _after_ the `\min`.  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks for the heads up :)  I will add the preamble bit next time.  The course I'm taking requires us to learn how to use LaTex.  They've given us an assignment template that has the preamble already done.  However, I've had to add some packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX forces the *scriptstyle* when typesetting denominators in display math.

This way the `min` operator loses the limits, which are typeset in a `nolimit` way.

I suggest to typeset `\limits` as suggestd by PeterGrill:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    s_j=\frac{e_j}{\min\limits_{1 \leq k \leq m-1} \big\{ t_{jk} + t_{j(k+1)} \big\}}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image]

As correctly remarked by @Thurston, you can also achieve a similar using the `\displaystyle` cmmand, which yields the same result here, **but it's not recommended since it changes all of the group style.** Anyway here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    s_j=\frac{e_j}{\displaystyle\min_{1 \leq k \leq m-1} \big\{ t_{jk} + t_{j(k+1)} \big\}}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Outputting:

[image]

Comment: You could also force it into display style with `...{\displaystyle\min_{...`

Comment: @Moriambar Better `\limits`.

Comment: @egreg since it won't change the rest of the styles?

Comment: @Moriambar Yes, indeed.